# Split array as input parameter

Tags: arrays, class, vba, module

In a class module named, I have

```
Private pARRactivityPred() As String

Public Property Let predArray(Value() As String)
    pARRactivityPred = Value

End Property
```

And calling it:

```
record.predArray = Split(string1, ",")
```

However, i am not sure why i get the following error:

> "Compile error: Definitions of property procedures for the same
>   property are inconsistent, or property procedure has an optional
>   parameter, a ParamArray, or an invalid set or final parameter"

Does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
Dim s() As String
s = Split("a,b,c,d", ",")
record.predArray = s
```

`record.predArray` expects a String array as input, but `Split` returns a Variant array, which causes a type mismatch error. Here I convert the output of `Split` to a String array and it works. This conversion can be done automatically using the assignment operator `=` as above, but it won't work through the input parameter of a procedure like `predArray`. The parameter has to be of the specific type specified in the procedure declaration: `Value() As String`.

I see that @mehow pressed the "answer" button a minute before I did :-)  However I think that using a loop to convert from Variant array to String array like he does is unnecessarily long-winded.

However I am unable to reproduce your exact error. With your code I get a compile-time "type mismatch" error for the reasons outlined above -- not the error you describe.